# Can iBeacon packets 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 0c 0e?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, packet

Is iBeacon Advertising data is started to

02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15

or

02 01 06 1a ff 4c 00 02 15??

I captured sample Advertising packets however, it started to

02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 0c 0e

I known as last 2 byte is data type and data length that always same value :(

it is not iBeacon packets? plz explain to me ;(

Comment: Both packets are Proximity Beacons. One looks exactly from iBeacon (because no EDR flag), the other one probablt from other Proximity Beacon (or emulator) because EDR and General Discoverablty flags set. [Format](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201492492-iBeacon-advertising-packet-structure), [Flags](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/29083/ble-advertising-data-flags-field-and-discovery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0x0215 value is a two byte beacon type code associated with iBeacon.  Both iOS CoreLocation and a properly configured Android Beacon Library will recognize this byte sequence as an iBeacon transmission, decode it and respond with detection callbacks.

The 0x0c0e is a a different byte sequence that is not associated with any beacon type code I have seen on my 5 years of work in the beacon industry.  it may not be a beacon advertisement at all, but a more general manufacturer advertisement used for other purposes.  it may also be a custom beacon format that is not widely known.

You will. red to check with the device manufacturer to see which of the two is the case.  If it is a custom beacon format, you can use the Android Beacon Library's BeaconParser class to configure it to detect this beacon type, but you will still need to get the specs of the format from the manufacturer.